# RubyMine crash on strart

Tags: 13.10, java

I'm trying to launch RubyMine on Ubuntu 13.10. But I get an error:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f3c371c010e, pid=3624, tid=139896602744576
JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  [libt2k.so+0x4210e]  fnt_InnerExecute+0x6e
Core dump written. Default location: /home/user/Software/RubyMine-6.0.3/bin/core or core.3624
An error report file with more information is saved as:
/home/user/Software/RubyMine-6.0.3/bin/hs_err_pid3624.log
If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
  http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I start it as a root - everything is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RubyMine installs completely within a user account.  There should be no need to run RubyMine with sudo or as root. Probably you started as root and locked the settings to him.  Check just a couple of things.

1. Check that your ~/.RubyMine50 (or ~/.RubyMine60) directory is owned by you and not root
2. Check whereever you unpacked your RubyMine environment to is also readable by your user and not root.

To change directory permissions:

```
sudo chown -vR user.user ~/.RubyMine50
```

where *user* is your user id.  Technically the 2nd one is *group*, but I only see Ubuntu set up each user as its own group.

Comment: I tried to do it, but i didn't solve my problem